# Jenkinsfile Helm Chart in Remote Repository

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, bitbucket, kubernetes-helm

I am having troubles accessing the `/charts` directory in the build process of my microservice because it is located into a different, remote repository.

I am trying to pull off something like this in my Groovy script:

`def chart_dir = "https://me@bitbucket.org/myteam/deployment.git/charts/"`

But I am not finding helpful resources online, and I am not sure what are the **best practices** for this kind of configuration.

Comment: Re: "_I am having troubles_": Is there any error msg? What's the behaviour you expect? What is the behaviour you experience? The line you mention is just a String definition. What do you do with this string?

Comment: I will update the question with all the required information

Comment: You could try something like the below that checks out the repo to a separate folder (in the workspace)
        checkout([
            $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<creds>',
            url: 'https://me@bitbucket.org/myteam/deployment.git/charts/']],
            extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'vconnect']]
        ])

Comment: Yeah I was actually thinking the same thing. I will keep this thread updated